# Azure Storage Voting Pattern

Tags: azure, design-patterns, storage

I'm investigating the use of Azure Storage for an application I have in mind. Part of it involves some SO-like functionality for voting and favourites. As with SO I'd like to be able to allow a user to vote/add favourites only once and use these for scoring/weighting purposes later on.

How would one go about doing this using Azure Storage, or AWS SimpleDB for that matter? Are there patterns for this type of scenario emerging?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using Table Storage? The tricky thing to keep in mind with Azure Storage is the lack of functions such as Count.

To prevent someone from voting or favoring something twice you'll need to make the primary key include the content's ID and the user's ID. Lets say a User can vote on a Comment. We'll create a table called CommentVotes with a PartitionKey of "UserID" and RowKey of "CommentID". Now any duplicates will throw an exception and prevent it from happening. The problem is calculating the Count on things without grabbing all the rows. You'll need to create another table which stores aggregated results which gets incremented when an insert is successful. That table might look like PK "Comments", RK "CommentID", TotalVotes "5".

Answer (score 1):

You can choose a couple ways to leverage storage: BLOBs (binary large objects) or Tables. Blobs just store text or binary data. Tables provide a little more structure. Furthermore, they provide REST services to manage them.

If you need "persistent and durable" storage options, Microsoft says that Azure Storage is perfect for that. However, if your application is subject to changes in the way that most applications are, I'd recommend using SQL Azure. SQL is much more common for storing application data. Azure storage is more useful for leveraging diagnostic logs and such without the need for setting up a SQL db (or to write problems with connecting to the database, themselves).

Another use for storage could be partitioning out your information so different people can access them. For example, you put all the diagnostics and error information into one location for an Ops team and then create another storage location for Managers who need a simple file that contains a report, which your application generates. Each storage location can have it's own identifier and connection hash string (sorry, I don't know what they're officially called).

Also, you can use storage for deployment and build purposes. I believe Visual Studio uses storage for propping a deployment when configuring it to deploy via the IDE. My point is, more people find SQL useful for application data and storage for operational data.

One pattern that I like but haven't seen implemented yet is the use of Azure Queues. The usefulness becomes apparent when you want to scale your application with a couple different types of roles. For example, a web role can use the Queue to add transactions and have two or more worker roles picking transactions off of the queue for processing and storage. Typically, the bottleneck in many Azure applications is the database, so moving the processing of data out of the web roles into worker roles is useful when scalability is a concern.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution consist of using 1 blob per counter (aka Blob Storage). The **blob would actually contain not just the final count but the *identifiers* of the voting users as well**. This would ensure no double voting. Open source libraries such as [Lokad.Cloud](http://code.google.com/p/lokad-cloud/) can help you for this (disclaimer: I work at Lokad).

One drawback of this approach is that you counter won't scale above ~10 votes / second - which is already *a lot* for most web apps. Then, if you are really thinking about super-heavy duty counters, you should think of **sharded counters** which can be implemented both with Table Storage and Blob Storage.

Another angle to look at this is to think [CQRS](http://abdullin.com/cqrs/), and let the voting issue a command message for async processing while Javascript takes care of providing immediate feedback to the user. The most notable benefit here is that it becomes possible to have a **single blob representing the entire state of the page**, voting counters along with other stuff to **speed-up reads**. Check [Lokad.CQRS](http://code.google.com/p/lokad-cqrs/) to do this.

Answer (score 0):

One of the challenges when you plan a distributed system is convince yourself that you should replicate the information in different places, that's data denormalization. Most of us are used to the data normalization, in databases and all that, trying to keep every information type only in one single place. But know we have to do the opposite for the performance's and distributivity sake.

As @Vyrotek has already pointed out, you should keep the "count" information stored somewhere else and update it yourself every time that an element is voted.